# IOS google maps camera not point to the marker

Tags: ios, google-maps, marker, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a view controller in a story board and i want to show a google map on it

everything went good, i got the get and i can show the map

my problem is that the camera is not pointing to the marker

here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"we are in the show stadium");
    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                            longitude:151.20
                                                                 zoom:6];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.mynewmap = mapView_;

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
    marker.title = @"Sydney";
    marker.snippet = @"Australia";
    marker.map = mapView_;
}
```

where `mynewmap`is an UIView outlet

here is what I see

[image]

the marker is on austrail but the camera not pointing to it and the marker is not on the map

Comment: I wonder why you downvote? i have a problem i tried to solve it but i couldn't

Comment: see what happens if you comment out 'self.mynewmap = mapView_;' setting myLocation Enabled should show an icon in the bottom right of the map.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with Storyboards, set the class of mynewmap to GMSMapView in Interface Builder.

And in viewDidLoad just add the camera, you don't need to alloc the view because it will be already allocated:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                        longitude:151.20
                                                             zoom:6];


    self.mynewmap.camera = camera;
}
```

Or try not creating your view with a Zero rect.. CGRectZero... you could try with:

`mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.mynewmap.frame camera:camera];`

Answer (score 0):

Your current location & (-33.86,151.20) locations are same ya not ... You have enabled userlocation mode. Please try again after comment

```
 //mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
```

remove this line ... Because It's also tracking userlocation.  May be help full.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after you are done with adding marker

```
[mapView_ animateToLocation:marker.position];
```

or use

```
[mapView_ animateToCameraPosition:[GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:marker.position.latitude
                                                                      longitude:marker.position.longitude
                                                                           zoom:6.0f]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue in iOS 11, instead of setting the GMSMapView from the storyboards, initialized it in the viewDidLoad method of the viewcontroller like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Force the view to layout to get its proper frame
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    // Initialize the GMSMapView with target view's bounds
    googleMapView = GMSMapView(frame: self.mapView.bounds)
    // Add the GMSMapView to the map container view
    self.mapView.addSubview(googleMapView)
}
```